# Reducer output to different files based on keys

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is it possible to write the output of a reducer to different files based on keys?

for example, if I feed the following data to the reducer:

```
(Key, Value) ==> (1, A) (1, B) (2, C) (2, D)
```

The output should be written to 2 different files output1 and output2,

output1 must contain:

```
(key, Value) ==> (1, [A,B])
```

output2 must contain:

```
(key value) ==> (2, [C,D])
```

Can somebody guide me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Default partitioner is `HashPartitoner`.

They guarentees that same key ends up in same Reducer.

If you need to output same value with different key to one files - 
You can use `Custom Partitioners` for that.

```
eg: 1,[A,B,G,M]
    1,[A,K,I,Y]
    2,[G,A,O]
    2,[U]
```

If you need A containing values in same reducer you can use custom partitioner.

In this particular eg we  break Reduce theory(Same key goes into same Reducer).While implementing custom partitioner

```
1,[A,B,G,M] 
1,[A,K,I,Y] 
2,[G,A,O]
```

goes into 1 Reducer even though they are not the same key.

Check this [link](http://hadooptutorial.wikispaces.com/Custom+partitioner)

Also go through [Custom Partitioner : N number of keys to N different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609575/custom-partitioner-n-number-of-keys-to-n-different-files)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to accomplish this is to use [MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html). It will allow you to specify multiple output destinations and when to write to them within your reducer.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for *MultipleOutputs*. It allows you to write data to numerous destinations (files, NoSQL Databases like Redis, ...). This link should get you started : http://yaseminavcular.blogspot.fr/2011/04/hadoop-multipleoutputformat.html